(Why) does setting boundaries between your professional and personal life reduce stress?
It is suggested in many articles, although without much evidence that putting boundaries between work-nonwork life is a good technique to reduce or manage stress.
Do we know why, if, such a technique works?
To help the question, I can only reflect from my personal observations. I find myself more irritable, angry and stressed when I fail to put a clear boundary between my immediate work and my next action. It doesn't even have to be a work-nonwork boundary. It could be a hobby I am working on, and if I don't put the hobby work aside by certain cleanup rituals, and keep partially thinking about it, anything I do afterwards gets less attention. If I am listening to my child or wife at that point I get quickly stressed.
Although I am not learned in psychology nor neuroscience, I feel there could be a connection between the short-term memory being full and the reduced the ability of the brain to perceive new information at that level? Or perhaps another mechanism could be from CBT approach, where the brain has learned the negative thoughts of not completing a job because of external interruptions, and thus triggers flight response, i.e. stress in such cases?
I wonder if there's a study on this aspect of the brain function.
